# AS3: Find parent of specified type

Tags: actionscript-3

I have this repeating pattern thoughout my code:

```
var scroller:Object = target;
while(scroller != null && !(scroller is Scroller) ) {
    if(scroller.hasOwnProperty('parent')) {
        scroller = scroller.parent;
    } else return;
}
```

What I want is to make a generic function to call like so:

`var scroller: Scroller = Scroller(dotParent(target, Class(Scroller)));`

But I'm new to the language (I come from C#), so I don't know what to use for the comparison. I need it to handle any type, not just scrollers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the example of a such function:

```
protected function dotParent(target:DisplayObject, parentClass:Class):DisplayObject
{
    var res:DisplayObject = target;
    while(res && !(res is parentClass)) 
    {
        if(res.parent) 
        {
            res = res.parent;
        } 
        else
        { 
            return null;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Test:

```
    //create test display list: stage->movieclip->sprite
    var sp:DisplayObject = (addChild(new MovieClip()) as MovieClip).addChild(new Sprite());

    var st: Stage = dotParent(sp, Stage) as Stage;
    trace(st);
    var mc: MovieClip = dotParent(sp, MovieClip) as MovieClip;
    trace(mc);
    var sh: Shape = dotParent(sp, Shape) as Shape;
    trace(sh);
```

output:

```
[object Stage]
[object MovieClip]
null
```